# cannot change default content-type when uploading video to S3 bucket using dio FormData and Multipart (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-s3, dio

```
 1.final formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(
    file.path,
    filename: fileName,
    contentType: MediaType.parse('video/mp4'),
  ),
});

2.final response = await dio.put<dynamic>(endpoint, data: formData, options: Options(contentType: 'video/mp4'));

  return response.data;
```

above I changed the content type to `video/mp4` (I tried both ways separately) but I am still `getting multipart/form-data; boundary=--dio-boundary-3846454268`
After changing content type is should also change to `video/mp4`  in S3 bucket console, it didn't change and because of that I am getting corrupted file in S3 bucket although I successfully uploaded a video. Looks like default content type in Multipart request is not changing although I tried both ways.

Any ideas how to change the default content type of Dio Multipart request in Flutter?
Thanks

Comment: According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html you shouldn't be using a multipart form as the body. Why don't you use the 'official' S3 package? https://pub.dev/packages/amplify_storage_s3

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just have a presigned aws url to upload file. How can I use that url with S3 official package?

Comment: See second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648883/flutter-dio-upload-image-using-binary-body-with-dio-package - skip wrapping the content in a multipart for and just send it. (If it's small enough you can simply read it into memory and then send the contents of the byte buffer.)